# Understanding PostgreSQL select operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getid() RETURNS table(id integer) AS $$
DECLARE
rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    select id into rec from player where id = 3;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from getid();
```

And when I'm trying to execute that script I got the error:

```
column reference "id" is ambiguous
```

Why? I thought that `id` column of the returned table is not participate in the select operator...

The issue is that it worked on `PostgreSQL 8.4` but doesn't work on `PosgtreSQL 9.4`. Couldn't you explain what actually has been added in the `PostgreSQL 9.4` so it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres is confused when you use the same names for arguments and columns... Consider using a convention with some prefix for all input parameters - for example p_id
I would write:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getid() RETURNS table(p_id integer) AS $$
DECLARE
rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO rec id FROM player WHERE id = 3;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve that specific problem you would do this in your select:

```
SELECT player.id INTO rec FROM player WHERE player.id = 3;
```